# Simple way to make python programs communicate

Tags: python

I have an RDB (let say an SQLite). I wrote a module that connects to the RDB and can aggregates some results (to get basic statistics about my data). Let's call this module "aggregator". Now I would like to write a local client that sends requests to my aggregator module to ask it some calculations (let's call this module client), wait for the answer and print it when it gets returned for example (or use it for anything else).

In my situation both of my modules (client and aggregator) are local (and I am working on a Linux).

I would like to find a simple way to make both system interact.

I have heard about "DBus" but I am wondering if it is suitable in my situation (and if it is not overkill).

Comment: You could use any broker like 0mq, rabbitmq or redis

Comment: the two could communicate over a `socket`.

Comment: It is often a good idea to let the RDB make the aggregation using function. Then client that can connect can fetch aggregate. If your are using SQLite, you may want to write a module that perform this kind of aggregation and then the client relies on this module, instead of starting multiprocessing and POSIx communication.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen not only rabbitmq, 0mq and redis have unix socket interface,  too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use sockets. Python makes it super easy to do: you have the standard [socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) library, with which you can pass [pickle-dumped](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwidjYmg6ePMAhUEfRoKHRKAC4sQFgguMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F2%2Flibrary%2Fpickle.html&usg=AFQjCNE13YnDcbSQzF3bDrL6gKHPVeKsRA&sig2=eH2RJ4Fyior2pddrfCsrlA) objects, [dumped json](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwifjMLG6ePMAhVDiRoKHW3lDxIQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F2%2Flibrary%2Fjson.html&usg=AFQjCNFiLEED27MDtmxWsDKmgOExf7ZYbw&sig2=dpo4SzR29B-G9HQxvZa9LQ&bvm=bv.122129774,d.d2s) or just strings between your programs.

Comment: Ok, it seems a nice idea, I was just wondering if it was adequate for "local" communication. I thought I would use it for programs on distant server but actually some developer seem to agree about using it locally.

Comment: Sockets are just a way to communicate between programs easily. Yes, they are widely used for communication over the web but are just as good for local communication.